# Write ExoPlayer output to a file

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exoplayer

I have an instance of `SimpleExoPlayer` with a chain of `AudioProcessors` (`audioProcessor1`, `audioProcessor2`, etc). So my input goes through a series of processing. I would like to capture the processed output and write it to a file.

I tried using the [TeeAudioProcessor](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/audio/TeeAudioProcessor.html) which does write the output to a file. But it only writes what is currently being playing since this class is made for debugging purposes. However what I want to achieve is to output to file immediately the full input. In other words, the user has an audio file and user clicks on "save" and the App will write a new file with all processing done.

**Update:**
As suggested, ExoPlayer's Transformer seems like the way to go here. https://exoplayer.dev/transforming-media.html

I forked it and modified it to include my audio processors and managed to make it work with some m4a files I have. However, it fails with mp3 or wav files with the following exception:

```
2022-02-08 18:17:13.268 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The output does not contain any tracks. Check that at least one of the input sample formats is supported.
2022-02-08 18:17:13.268 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.transformer.Transformer$TransformerAnalyticsListener.onTracksChanged(Transformer.java:634)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.268 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.analytics.AnalyticsCollector.lambda$onTracksChanged$35(AnalyticsCollector.java:588)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.268 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.analytics.-$$Lambda$AnalyticsCollector$7tg5KkucYfjKC8XMa7Ki5D-f7tE.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.268 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.ListenerSet$ListenerHolder.invoke(ListenerSet.java:297)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.268 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.ListenerSet.lambda$queueEvent$0(ListenerSet.java:184)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.268 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.-$$Lambda$ListenerSet$NbKDn9xtItiyMgYZmjIx_Sv1FFQ.run(Unknown Source:6)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.268 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.ListenerSet.flushEvents(ListenerSet.java:205)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.268 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.ListenerSet.sendEvent(ListenerSet.java:220)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.268 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.analytics.AnalyticsCollector.sendEvent(AnalyticsCollector.java:797)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.analytics.AnalyticsCollector.onTracksChanged(AnalyticsCollector.java:585)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.lambda$updatePlaybackInfo$10(ExoPlayerImpl.java:1035)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.-$$Lambda$ExoPlayerImpl$VXzfUrPSnMl-ySIw0FPLtylNgIY.invoke(Unknown Source:6)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.ListenerSet$ListenerHolder.invoke(ListenerSet.java:297)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.ListenerSet.lambda$queueEvent$0(ListenerSet.java:184)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.-$$Lambda$ListenerSet$NbKDn9xtItiyMgYZmjIx_Sv1FFQ.run(Unknown Source:6)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.ListenerSet.flushEvents(ListenerSet.java:205)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.updatePlaybackInfo(ExoPlayerImpl.java:1101)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.handlePlaybackInfo(ExoPlayerImpl.java:965)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.lambda$new$1$ExoPlayerImpl(ExoPlayerImpl.java:181)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.-$$Lambda$ExoPlayerImpl$nOBJYkeEQ2uz3sBKLToLWmzrgZk.run(Unknown Source:4)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
2022-02-08 18:17:13.269 6746-6746/com.android.transformertest W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Even if I follow the same code in this simple tutorial [here](https://exoplayer.dev/transforming-media.html) (without any modifications to the Transformer), the same exception is thrown. This is thrown from the Transformer's `onTracksChanged` where the `muxerWrapper` has 0 track count. I also noticed that the `TrackSelectionArray` has a `null` item.

Is there a way to make it work with any audio formats as input?

Comment: Can you use transformers for this https://exoplayer.dev/transforming-media.html?

Comment: @YuriSchimke Thanks for the comment. I wasn't aware of it. It sounds promising. Check my updated question for more info. I'd appreciate if you have any further feedback. Thanks!

Comment: File a bug on the project?

Comment: "make it work with any audio formats as input" is quite an absurd demand. If you have forked it, just open a PR and see how this PR will merely get ignored - and for which concrete reasons.

Comment: Well @MartinZeitler ExoPlayer team did address my issue on Github and mentioned that this is fixed in the upcoming version of ExoPlayer.

Comment: You could add an addAnalyticsListener and implement (for example) the onEvents and save the items into an ArrayList.